# Disabling password login for certain users for SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I added this to the bottom of the sshd_config file

```
Match User user
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

Then I restarted SSH, and when I went to go SSH into my server I got the error

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

How do I make it so a specific user can login to the server without entering a password or needing a key?

Comment: Wait. You want to allow remote logins **without a password OR a key?!?** What on earth could be a valid reason for doing this?

Comment: I was just trying to find out if it was even possible.

Comment: You can leave your car doors unlocked and the keys in the ignition too. It _might_ not get stolen.

Answer (score 4):

SSH assumes that you are using *some* type of authentication, be it password, key auth, kerberos, etc. By setting `PasswordAuthentication no`, you're just telling your sshd that it should not allow that as a possible authentication method. It still needs **some** sort of authentication, though.

I suppose there would be a way to do this using PAM if you really, really, really wanted to disable all authentication, but this is a very, very, very ill-advised course of action.

Don't do it.

When set up correctly, key auth is just as transparent as using no password, and is **much** more secure.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at rsh with a rhosts file. It's insecure, but so is ssh without authentication. I would recommend you set up passwordless ssh keys if you need to do something like this.